# Grunt clean task hangs

Tags: gruntjs

I've created a simple `Gruntfile` for creating minimized distribution, and it works. Now I've added a task that should delete that distribution:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
        build: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                src: '**/*.js',
                dest: 'build/js',
                cwd: 'js/'
            }]
        }
    },
      clean: {
        build: ["build/"]
      }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
  grunt.registerTask('clean', ['clean']);

};
```

However, when I type `grunt clean`, the command line hangs. There is no error, no warning, simply hanging. The `Node.js` system process shows 15% CPU consumption in Task Manager (so one CPU is fully utilized).

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
  grunt.registerTask('clean', ['clean']);
```

You are registering a task called clean and then recursively calling it.
You cannot register a task with the same name as an already defined task. You need to rename it:

```
 grunt.registerTask('customClean', ['clean',"additionalTasks"]);
```

Otherwise remove the `registerTask` call completely as `grunt clean`  is already defined.